# How make a list and track the position of item in a Codable Struct?

Tags: swift, struct, firebase-analytics, codable

I have this struct :

```
struct Item: Codable {
    let uniqueId: String
    let id: String
    let productId: String
    let name: String
    let price: String
    let listPrice: String
    let sellingPrice: String
    let totalRow: String
    let additionalInfo: AdditionalInfo
    let productCategoryIds: String
    let productCategories: [String: String]
    var quantity: Int
    let seller: String
    let imageUrl: String
    let detailUrl: String
    let availability: String
    let measurementUnit: String
    let unitMultiplier: Double
}
```

I need track the position of item .
In another view and struct, i used firstIndex(of: item)

```
let index = orderForm?.items.firstIndex(of: item) ?? 0
itemDictionary[TagParameterFirebase.index] = index.
```

But Xcode show me an error because this struct is CODABLE, the another struct is EQUATABLE.

What can i do?

I need send a event whit the index of the product.

Answer (score 0):

If `uniqueId` is what it suggests use the other API which does not require `Equatable`

```
let index = orderForm?.items.firstIndex{$0.uniqueId == item.uniqueId} ?? 0
```

Alternatively adopt `Equatable` which is pretty easy

```
struct Item: Codable, Equatable  {

    static func ==(lhs: Item, rhs: Item) -> Bool {
        lhs.uniqueId == rhs.uniqueId
    }
    
    let uniqueId: String
    let id: String
...
```

Comment: in the view, the API it is . i CANT change this. I tried the alternatively , but the position arrived me in 0 always (sorry my english is poor) haha